# Почему мой код не работает в методе?

Tags: c#

Пробую сделать функцию но она почему то не работает, пишет что требуется ссылка.
Как правильно написать?

```csharp
static void inputValidationLogin ()
{

    string prText = textBoxMyName.Text;
    MessageBox.Show(prText);

}

private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

  inputValidationLogin();

}
```

Comment: Как именно пишет? prText где объявлено?

Comment: @MBo обьявил, но что то всервно не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том что вы пытаетесь напрямую получить текс из эдита в статической так называемой функцией.

Вы можете сделать метод нестатическим:

```
void inputValidationLogin()
{
  prText = textBoxMyName.Text;
  MessageBox.Show(prText);
}
```

Или можно просто передавать значение текстового поля через входящие параметры:

```
static void inputValidationLogin(string inStr)
{
    MessageBox.Show(inStr);
}
```

Вызывается так:

```
inputValidationLogin(textBoxMyName.Text);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это получается я не верно указываю модификаторы доступа?

Comment: Если в методе inputValidationLogin пишу return; код всеравно выполняется далее.
Подскажите если можете, как из метода inputValidationLogin остановить дальнейшее выполнения кода?

Comment: @AnatolyDev статические методы могут обращаться только к статическим членам класса, текстовое поле не считается статическим. И static является модификатором, но не доступа, подробнее можешь почитать в документации https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/

Comment: метод указал просто void inputValidationLogin() все работает. Но не могу понять как остановить выполнение кода. Если пишу return то происходит только выход из метода и все. Извините если что, только питаюсь разобраться с этим языком.

Comment: @AnatolyDev если вы хотите полностью закрыть программу то Application.Exit();

Comment: нет, я просто хочу остановить ее а не выйти. Это возможно сделать?

Comment: @AnatolyDev без код тогда помочь не смогу